# Label Data lost when scrolling in UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, delegates

I made a table view with a label that increments and decrements on pressing a button and another button to show the text in another label outside the UItableView. Everything works fine but when I scroll the Tableview the value resets to zero!

[Before Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noVRk.png)
[After Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Gpp.png)

My ViewController class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

var numArray = [Value]()
var initialValue = 0


@IBOutlet weak var tableView : UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblOutput : UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for _ in 0 ... 100{
        numArray.append(Value(number: initialValue))
    }
    self.lblOutput.text = "\(initialValue)"

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.reloadData()
    
}
}

 extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",for: indexPath) as? ControllerTableViewCell else{fatalError("Error in creating cells")}

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.data = numArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblInput.text = "\(cell.data.number)"
    
    return cell
}
}

extension ViewController : MyTableViewCellDelegate{
  func DidPrint(Data: String) {
    self.lblOutput.text = "\(Data)"
}
}
```

My TableViewCell class

```
protocol MyTableViewCellDelegate : AnyObject {
   func DidPrint(Data: String)
 }


class ControllerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

weak var delegate : MyTableViewCellDelegate?
var data : Value!

private var counterValue = 0

@IBOutlet var lblInput : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var btnPrint : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnPlus : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnMinus : UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}


@IBAction func DidPressPrint(){
    self.data.number = counterValue
    delegate?.DidPrint(Data: "\(data.number)")
    print(data.number)
}
@IBAction func DidPressPlus(){
    counterValue += 1
    data.number = counterValue
    self.lblInput.text = "\(data.number)"
}
@IBAction func DidPressMinus(){
    if(counterValue > 0){
                counterValue -= 1
                data.number = counterValue
            }
    else{
        counterValue = 0
        data.number = 0
    }
    self.lblInput.text = "\(data.number)"
}


}
```

My Data Model

```
import Foundation

struct Value{
  var number : Int
}
```

Comment: That's because you are not updating the data source.

Comment: @ElTomato can you explain more about it?

Answer (score 0):

As @El Tomato suggested, you are not updating your data source, that's why your changes gets "forgotten" on scroll.

Try to move your `didPressPlus`, `didPressMinus` and `didPressPrint` in your `ViewController` class and redefine your table view delegate like below.
By passing the `tag` attributes to the buttons, you can then retrieve the index of the item pressed in the functions and edit the correct data source item.
Also remove the unnecessary `MyTableViewCellDelegate`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

    var numArray = [Value]()
    var initialValue = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView : UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblOutput : UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for _ in 0 ... 100 {
            numArray.append(Value(number: initialValue))
        }
        self.lblOutput.text = "\(initialValue)"

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource 
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? ControllerTableViewCell else {fatalError("Error in creating cells")}
        let indexItem = indexPath.row
        let valueItem = numArray[indexItem]

        cell.lblInput.text = valueItem.number

        cell.btnMinus.tag = indexItem
        cell.btnMinus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressMinus(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.btnPlus.tag = indexItem
        cell.btnPlus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressPlus(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.btnPrint.tag = indexItem
        cell.btnPrint.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressPrint(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

    @objc private func didPressPlus(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let dataIndex = sender.tag
        if numArray.count < dataIndex { return }

        let numArrayItem = numArray[dataIndex]

        if (numArrayItem.number >= 0) {
            numArray[dataIndex].number -= 1
        } 

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @objc private func didPressMinus(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let dataIndex = sender.tag
        if numArray.count < dataIndex { return }

        numArray[dataIndex].number += 1

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @objc private func didPressPrint(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let dataIndex = sender.tag
        if numArray.count < dataIndex { return }

        self.lblOutput.text = "\(numArray[dataIndex].number)"
    }
}
```

In order to move the three methods in the `ViewController` you'll need to remove the two correspondent `IBAction` from the `UITableViewCell` class.
Also, remove the linkage with the `ControllerTableViewCell` actions.
Here is the resulting `ControllerTableViewCell`:

```
class ControllerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var lblInput : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var btnPrint : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnPlus : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnMinus : UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight but how I can move my didPressPlus and didPressMinus in ViewController? Can you elaborate on this also please? I'm newbie in swift

Comment: @ChetanjeevSinghBains I've just edited the answer adding an explanation, let me know if it's still unclear to you.

Comment: I am getting an error on sender.view?.tag that (UIButton has no member View). How can i resolve this?

Comment: My bad, you can access the `tag` property directly if the parameter is a `UIButton`. Try with the edited code.

Comment: the cell.btnMinus.addTarget is creating an issue. Is that the correct form?
Error : 1) Consecutive line must be seperated by ';' 2) Expected ')' to complete #selector expression 3) expected expression.

Comment: Yeah there was an error with the brackets, check the answer now.

Comment: Thanks it's working now. I appreciate your time. My didPrint function is not working now I'll look into that matter.

Comment: With the same idea of the two methods before, you should move the didPrint function into your delegate, remove the `MyTableViewCellDelegate` and clear your `UITableViewCell` class. Check the edited answer.